# sqlalchemy filter by data from other relationship table

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-3.6

I have user table:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    UserID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    FirstName = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    # relationships
    Emails = db.relationship('Email', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
```

with emails table:

```
class Email(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user_emails"

    Email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    UserID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.UserID'), nullable=False)
```

how do i filter or find user based on email?

i tried below but it doesnt work:

```
DBModel.query.filter(DBModel.Emails.any(Email=searchInput))
DBModel.query.filter_by(Emails=searchInput).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with this:

```
DBModel.query.join(DBModel.Emails).filter_by(Email=id).first()
```